# How to generate a model with has_one contraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create 2 models, where one belongs to another. I know the generate command to create a model that “belongs_to” another but I have no clue how to have the other model have “has_one”.

Can I specify “has_one” in the generate command? Or do I manually add it to the model file after?

This still confuses me since the child that “belongs_to” has the foreign key and the parent that “has_one” doesn’t have anything.

And isn’t this a one-to-one relationship, and so not needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use some concrete terms for examples. We'll say a user has one profile.

To generate the user and profile, you could use:

```
rails generate model User email:string username:string
rails generate model Profile user:references about_me:text
```

So yes, you do have to add the line `has_one :profile` to the user model. No, you don't have to add the line `belongs_to :user` to the profile model as this will be added for you.

As for your last question, I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, this is a one-to-one relationship, but what part do you think is not needed? The `has_one :profile` line?

If that's the part you're not understanding, you're not fully understanding what this line gives you. It adds useful methods to the User class, most important of which are probably `@user.build_profile` and `@user.profile`. Might not seem like much, but pretty cool for adding just one line of code imho.

Comment: It all makes sense now, it allows for both tables to know they have reference to each other with only one having a foreign key. Thank you. Kinda sucks that you have to add has_one manually though. Is there a way to add this in a migrate file?